# Onclick opens URL in new TAB but not the second URL in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I've got some help here a few days ago, but the the answer I've got did not work for me eventually and I am still looking how to fix the issue.

I have this page test:

http://cpanel2.secured.co.il/~iherbcoi/test.html

I have many links that include:

1. A URL that opens in HREF in a new TAB.
2. An onclick event that opens a second URL inside an iframe on the source page.

I've taken the original link that worked good and wanted to change the onclick URL into a value that will be taken from a JS from the HEAD of the page.

This was my original HREF/onclick that worked fine:

```
<a href="http://www.cnn.com" target="_blank" onClick=document.getElementById("if").src='http://www.yahoo.com';>Original Link</a>
```

The issue is that the URL that opens in iframe is the same as the one that opened in a new TAB, instead of the onclick URL.

I also have an issue that cause the page source to refresh in a whole once the iframe is loading its content. How can avoid this please?

This is the code that is used at the moment:

The HEAD code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Link() {
            document.getElementById("iframe_test").href = "http://www.yahoo.com";
        }
</script>
```

The link:

```
<a href="http://www.cnn.com" onClick="window.open(this.href)" target="iframe_test">JS HEAD code based link</a>
```

The iframe:

```
<iframe id="iframeid" name="iframe_test" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="400px" height="400px"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood, try `onclick="Link()"` to actually call the function in your script. At the moment you are telling the window to open the href in the iframe.

Then change your target back to `_blank`

You also have a few typos which will stop stuff being called

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.cnn.com" onclick="Link()" target="_blank">Click</a>

<iframe id="iframe_test" src="" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="400px" height="400px"></iframe>
```

JS:

```
function Link() {

   document.getElementById("iframe_test").src = "http://www.yahoo.com";

}
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, but the issue is that I don't know how to call the function. That is my problem. Can you please show me what I need to correct? I've got a few options to my script, but they can been seen hidden inside tags on my test page source. Maybe they are more right?

Comment: @Guy have edited the answer with updated code. Bear in mind when I tried to open 'yahoo.com' in an iframe there is a X-Origin error as yahoo doesn't allow their site to be shown in an iframe. I'm guessing your actual use case is different though

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!